# draw red border around wrong text

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to implement a method which draws a red border around a Control like a text, if the user didn't enter anything. i'm using eclipse swt.
My Method looks like that:

```
protected void drawRedBorder(Control cont){
    final Control control = cont;
    cont.getParent().addPaintListener(new PaintListener(){
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e){
            GC gc = e.gc;
            Color red = new Color(null, 255, 0 ,0);
            gc.setBackground(red);
            Rectangle rect = control.getBounds();
            Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(rect.x - 2, rect.y - 2,
                    rect.width + 4, rect.height + 4);
            gc.setLineStyle(SWT.LINE_SOLID);
            gc.fillRectangle(rect1);
        }
    });
}
```

It works fine, when i call it when the dialog with the Textfield is created. However it doesn't work, when i call it in a Method like checkInput() which checks if the user hast entered something.

I tried to solve the problem by calling redraw() or update(), but nothing worked. Any clue how i can solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try `updateUI()`?

Comment: where can I call this method?

Comment: After you invoke `drawRedBorder` method.

Comment: I mean i can't find a method called updateUI()

Comment: Are you using `JFrame`?

Comment: @Sam Look at the tags and the code, it's SWT, not Swing...

Answer (score 0):

Try the below.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ModifyEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ModifyListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintListener;

import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main (String [] args) {


        Display display = new Display ();
        Shell shell = new Shell (display);
        final Text txt;
        txt= new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        drawRedBorder(txt);

        txt.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {

            @Override
            public void modifyText(ModifyEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                txt.getParent().redraw();

            }
        });


        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        shell.open ();
        while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
        }


        display.dispose ();
    }

    protected static void drawRedBorder(Control cont){
        final Control control = cont;

        cont.getParent().addPaintListener(new PaintListener(){
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent e){
               if(((Text) control).getText().length()<=0){
                    GC gc = e.gc;
                    Color red = new Color(null, 255, 0 ,0);
                    gc.setBackground(red);
                    Rectangle rect = control.getBounds();
                    Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(rect.x - 2, rect.y - 2,
                            rect.width + 4, rect.height + 4);
                    gc.setLineStyle(SWT.LINE_SOLID);
                    gc.fillRectangle(rect1);
               }
            }
        });
    }

}
```